# Got stack overflow when constructing std::function with std::bind result

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

void foo(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto f1 = std::bind(foo, 10, _1); // fine
    std::function<void (int)> f2 = f1; // fine
    auto f3 = std::bind(f2, 20); // fine
    std::function<void ()> f4 = f3; // stack overflow
    std::function<void ()> f5 = [=](){f3();}; // stack overflow
    f3();
    return 0;
}
```

I am writing a simple library and using `std::function` as callback for the library user.

I want something like `f4` to simplify the callback function.

I am not familiar with the `std::bind` internals.

Why `f3` could not construct `f4`?

I am using

clang++ : Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

on a OSX10.9 macbook

compiled with :

clang++ -g -std=c++0x test.cpp

stack overflow at f4 because infinite call of the flowing thing:

```
frame #0: 
frame #1:
...

frame #6361: 0x0000000100001ff2 a.out`std::__1::function<void ()>::function<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int> >(std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int>, std::__1::enable_if<__callable<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int> >::value, void>::type*) [inlined] std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__function::__base<void (this=0x00007fff5fbfeb00, this=0x0000000100103a90, __f=0x00007fff5fbff4e0, __a=0x00007fff5fbfeae8)>, std::__1::__allocator_destructor<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__function::__func<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int> >, void ()> > > >::get() const + 42 at functional:1007

frame #6362: 0x0000000100001fc8 a.out`std::__1::function<void (this=0x00007fff5fbff530, __f=0x00007fff5fbff4e0, =0x0000000000000000)>::function<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int> >(std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int>, std::__1::enable_if<__callable<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int> >::value, void>::type*) + 776 at functional:1285

frame #6363: 0x0000000100001a3d a.out`std::__1::function<void (this=0x00007fff5fbff530, __f=<unavailable>, =0x0000000000000000)>::function<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int> >(std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int>, std::__1::enable_if<__callable<std::__1::__bind<std::__1::function<void (int)>&, int> >::value, void>::type*) + 29 at functional:1289

frame #6364: 0x000000010000189c a.out`main + 956 at test.cpp:15
```

Comment: A run time stack overflow, or a compile time?  What compiler, and what version?

Comment: Does it happen if you omit the bind expression locals, i.e. assign the result of `std::bind` directly to `std::function` variables?

Comment: Produces expected results on clang++3.4 and g++4.8.1 (no stack overflow)

Comment: g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 also produces expected result

Comment: [Using lambdas instead of `std::bind` may be an effective workaround.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bde6f42bc84cf72)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in libc++.  It has been fixed.  If you're not using the latest version of Xcode, update.  If you are using the latest version of Xcode, you can find the very latest libc++ here:  http://libcxx.llvm.org .  This bug is definitely fixed in the svn repository.